# Working with Doctrine array of enum and store it in a separate table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm currently building Entity model and one of my Doctrine Entities have ManyToMany relation with an external dictionary (like ENUM). So the entity field will be an Array of Enum.

I'm looking for a way to have it as an array field on my entity, but to store it as a separate DB table.

Would like to get any advice/links/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've decided to create an Entity to store this relation. To make sure it will be deleted on unlinking from the parent entity, I've used the `orphanRemoval=true` option on the OneToMany relation side.

```
class Entity {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityType", mappedBy="entity", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $types;
}

class EntityType {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity")
     */
    protected $entity;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="MyEnum")
     */
    protected MyEnum $type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit out of context but..

A many to many is already an array (Iterator) in your entity.

You can create your own entity acting as a Many To Many and set the column as enum.

Comment: problem is that I don't need an entity for the 2nd side. I want my Entity to have ManyToMany to the class which is not an Entity.

Comment: I'm currently storing this as JSON and validating with @Assert\All({@Assert\Choice}). But this makes it a bit harder to query by this "relation".

Comment: What i meant is that you can create the ManyToMany relation yourself. You create a entity in the middle with all the attributes you want and link them via ManyToOne. In your entities you will have a OneToMany (which is an array).